# Javascript to Aura type coercion

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, tab, aura-attribute, winter19

Previously I was able to have the following component and init function, where the Id for lightning:tab would be implicitly coerced to String from Number.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="List" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:tabset>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.List}" var="a">
        <lightning:tab label="{!a.Name}" id="{!a.Number}">
            {!a.Name}
        </lightning:tab>

    </aura:iteration>

</lightning:tabset>
```

Init:

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var List = [];
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        var a = {
            Name: "a " + (i+1),
            Number: i
        }
        List.push(a);
    }
    component.set("v.List", List);
}
```

However, now in Winter '19 I have to explicitly define Number as i.toString() to be able to use the tabs correctly.

Are there any more examples of this stricter javascript -> aura/lightning definitions or is it just for this component?

tested this in communities btw.

Thank you

Comment: I'd update this myself, but I'm past my edit limit for the moment:  The last line in your javascript should be component.set("v.weekList", List);

Comment: What's the error message (if any)?  Very curious about this one.  Does the compiler really care whether the value it's returning (some number in place of {!wk.Number}) makes sense in context of the markup.

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld No error message, unless you debug it using Lightning Debug Chrome add-on. I suggest creating this yourself in a dev org to see the error in Winter '19. Then change "Number: i.toString()" to see it working as usual.